# String compareTo

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception

Does anybody know why `String.compareTo` is not programmed to behave more graciously in regards to a `null` parameter?

In my opinion the next sequence should return "1" or at least the javadoc should be more specific in regards to the NPE. `equals()` returns `false` in this case and I guess `equals` and `compareTo` should be consistent.

E.g.

```
String nullString = null;
System.out.println ("test".equals(nullString));
System.out.println ("test".compareTo(nullString));
```

Is throwing a NPE:

```
false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.compareTo(String.java:1177)
```

To add to it. If you were to make this compareTo in your code, would have you verified for nulls?

Comment: I think the javadoc is quite specific.

Comment: I guess there is not an universal answer, even you started with "in my opinion" so any decision is an arbitrary choice. Anyway I admit I agree with you, actual rule isn't very intuitive and it's not symmetric with equals but...it's by design...

Comment: Why should it return 1 and not -1 ? It doesn't make sense to define an ordering with nulls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it's the [documented behavior of `compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (emphasis added):

> The natural ordering for a class `C` is said to be *consistent with equals* if and only if `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0` has the same boolean value as `e1.equals(e2)` for every `e1` and `e2` of class `C`. Note that **`null` is not an instance of any class, and `e.compareTo(null)` should throw a `NullPointerException`** even though `e.equals(null)` returns `false`.

As for `.equals()` returning `false` instead of NPEing, again, it's in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

Comment: In this case equals should have thrown NPE as well.

Comment: @mihaisimi no it should not have, the contract of the interface explicitly states that e.equals(null) will yield false.  This is an important thing to recognize when implementing interfaces and using code written by others.

Comment: I think "null is not an instance of any class" is pretty weak. I understand it's by design but it's not consistent with equals(). Even if equals() accepts an object the equalsIgnoreCase() method is consistent (and it accepts a string).

Comment: @Adriano you don't have to make your case with me: that quote is straight from the JavaDoc. I agree, it's not completely consistent.

Comment: @Adriano I am curious what would you consider null to be than?

Comment: @MattBall I know and you had my +1, I commented here only 'cause you quoted javadoc!

Comment: @Woot4Moo I understand equals(null) returns false (null is not a string). I understand equalsIgnoreCase(null) because it must be consistent with equals(). I would expect compareTo(null) is consistent with equals (even if -1 or +1 for the result is pretty arbitrary).

Comment: @Adriano I agree that far as well.  The only thing I can think is that they were designing it similar to how NaN works when you do comparisons.

Comment: @Adriano the problem with `foo.compareTo(null)` always returning the same value is that `null` does not provide enough information to give a consistent ordering, particularly when the arguments are swapped: `null.compareTo(foo)` should _definitely_ NPE. I actually think this is a Good Thing, because the language is not imposing an arbitrary ordering of nulls (should they come before all other values, or after all other values?). In this regard, it is up to the programmer to decide. (continued)

Comment: @Adriano ...which is where Guava's [`Ordering.nullsFirst|Last()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#nullsFirst%28%29) comes in handy.

Comment: @MattBall of course there are good reasons for any design choice they made (= they're not random) but I'm pretty annoyed to treat null as a special case with an inconsistent behavior (null.equals(foo) throws NPE and it's OK, foo.equals(null) doesn't, foo.CompareTo(null) does). They loved to write documentation...

Answer (score 3):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29)

Compares this String to another Object. If the Object is a String, this function behaves like compareTo(String). Otherwise, it throws a ClassCastException (as Strings are comparable only to other Strings).

The only other option would be to throw a `ClassCastException` however, since there is a well defined exception for null references, the NPE is thrown instead.

Executing the following code:

```
void do()
{
    String s = null;
    System.out.println(s instanceof String); 
}
```

yields false.

Comment: It would call 'int compareTo(String anotherString)' though, ClassCastException is not applicable here

Comment: @jontro no it would not, see the updated code sample to validate the claim. In the above a String that is set to null is no longer a String.

Comment: You are right (by Java dogma). But I think the JDK generates bugs here and should be simplified.

Comment: @mihaisimi you can email James Gosling if you would like.

Comment: @Woot4Moo I don't think the ClassCastException argument is the right one in this case - MattBall's answer is the correct answer.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Overloading  is compile time. instanceof is runtime. compareTo(String) will be chosen.

Comment: cf JLS: "The null reference can always undergo a widening reference conversion to any reference type."

Answer (score 1):

It is generally understood that the Java SE class library documentation explicitly states when `null` is a valid parameter.  When there is no mention of `null` being a valid argument, you should assume that it is not, and that an exception may be thrown immediately, or later one.

And in this case, the javadoc for the `Comparable` interface specifically states that `null` is NOT a valid parameter for `Comparable,compareTo`.  (You can get there from the `String.compareTo` javadoc by clicking the "Specified by" link.)